# react-native-navigation: set custom header to all screen except one

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, header, react-native-navigation

I wanted to set a custom header to all screens inside a stack navigator except to particular a screen, because I wanted it to have the default header. I know that setting the header property of the options props of the navigator will do the trick to apply the custom header to all the screens, but my question is how to exclude one specific screen and just set it to default?

This is my current implementation for setting the custom header to all screens:

```
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    header: () => <CustomHeader />,
  }}
>
  <Stack.Screen name="Page1" component={Page1} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Page2" component={Page2} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Page3" component={Page3} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

What can I further add to this code to exclude the application of custom header to Page3?

Answer (score 1):

You can set Header for all screens. For anyone which you want to avoid you can set **headerShown** to **false**.

```
 <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator
            headerMode={'screen'}
            screenOptions={{
              header: ({navigation}) => <Header navigation={navigation} />,
            }}> // This custom Nav Header is for all screens

            <Stack.Screen
              name="Home"
              component={HomescreenTabs} 
              options={{headerShown: true}}// Will use Header component as Nav Header
            />
    
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Editor"
              component={Editor}
              options={{headerShown: false,}} // No Nav Header component will show
            />
    
            <Stack.Screen
              name="SearchList"
              component={SearchList}
              options={{headerShown: true}} // Will use Header component as Nav Header
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Page1" component={Page1} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Page2" component={Page2} />
      <Stack.Screen options={{ header: () => <CustomHeader /> }} name="Page3" component={Page3} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Actually you answered the original question, but I revised my question, I forgot to indicate it. What I really wanted is to remain the default header for specific screens after setting the custom header.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was wondering how to do the same for Drawer Navigator here is the solution that I have come up with:

```js
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';

const NavHeader = props => {
 // ... NavHeader code goes here 
};

export const withHeader = Component => {
  return props => {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <NavHeader {...props} />
        <Component {...props} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  };
};
```

Then in your Drawer you do:

```js
<Drawer.Navigator>
    <Drawer.Screen
      name={ROUTES.DASHBOARD}
      component={withHeader(DashboardContainer)} // <--- Wrap it around component here.
    />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

If you want all screens except one to have custom header you wrap up every component with `withHeader` except one.